# Footnote placement

Tags: footnotes

when trying to add a footnote for acknowledgements, the 1 doesn't align properly with the abstract. I have tried moving around `footnote{}` but this does not seem to help. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[margin=1in, includefoot]{geometry}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \onehalfspacing
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{siunitx}                        % added
\usepackage{threeparttable}   
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}    
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\itshape}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{
 \kern-3\p@
\hrule\@width \textwidth
\kern2.6\p@}
\makeatother
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
 \fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{ \thepage\ }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{rotating}



 \begin{document}


\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Wa.png}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{huge}
Does Corruption Affect Investment Decisions at The Firm-Level?
\end{huge}




\begin{abstract}

\centering\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-10cm}
This extensive study supported by enterprise data for European and Asian 
economies,  investigates whether corruption influences investment decisions 
made by firms. Here, corruption is more narrowly defined as the incidence of 
informal payments to government or public officials to ‘get things done’. 
Using panel data this analysis finds that paying bribes deters firms from 
investing in fixed assets, having controlled for endogeneity. This concurs 
with evidence presented in the literature. Moreover, when accounting for 
differences between the regions investigated, results show a negative yet 
insignificant relationship between bribery and investment for European 
firms. However, an insignificant positive relationship is found for firms in 
Asia, perhaps corroborating theories such as the ‘Efficient Grease 
Hypothesis’ whereby corruption helps lower bureaucratic red tape. 
Furthermore, this study contributes to the literature by also employing a 
reverse causality approach, analysing why such a relation between corruption 
and investment exists. This is conducted by examining whether bribery is 
more prevalent for short or long-term oriented firms, with results 
supporting the former. Finally, this mechanism is of particular interest for 
potential policy measures on battling bribery at the micro-level. 
\end{minipage}
\end{abstract}
\end{center}
\footnote{This paper has greatly benefitted from the expertise, advice and encouragement of Dr. Selma Walther}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does work:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[margin=1in, includefoot]{geometry}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \onehalfspacing
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{siunitx}                        % added
\usepackage{threeparttable}   
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}    
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\itshape}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{
 \kern-3\p@
\hrule\@width \textwidth
\kern2.6\p@}
\makeatother
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
 \fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{ \thepage\ }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{rotating}



 \begin{document}


\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image.png}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{huge}
Does Corruption Affect Investment Decisions at The Firm-Level?
\end{huge}




\begin{abstract}

\centering\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-10cm}
This extensive study supported by enterprise data for European and Asian 
economies,  investigates whether corruption influences investment decisions 
made by firms. Here, corruption is more narrowly defined as the incidence of 
informal payments to government or public officials to ‘get things done’. 
Using panel data this analysis finds that paying bribes deters firms from 
investing in fixed assets, having controlled for endogeneity. This concurs 
with evidence presented in the literature. Moreover, when accounting for 
differences between the regions investigated, results show a negative yet 
insignificant relationship between bribery and investment for European 
firms. However, an insignificant positive relationship is found for firms in 
Asia, perhaps corroborating theories such as the ‘Efficient Grease 
Hypothesis’ whereby corruption helps lower bureaucratic red tape. 
Furthermore, this study contributes to the literature by also employing a 
reverse causality approach, analysing why such a relation between corruption 
and investment exists. This is conducted by examining whether bribery is 
more prevalent for short or long-term oriented firms, with results 
supporting the former. Finally, this mechanism is of particular interest for 
potential policy measures on battling bribery at the micro-level.\footnotemark
\end{minipage}
\end{abstract}
\end{center}
\footnotetext{This paper has greatly benefitted from the expertise, advice and encouragement of Dr. Selma Walther}
\end{document}
```

[image: results]